# Maximise rigidity of acrylic rod/tube

Tags: stresses, material-science

I understand that for a given quantity of material a tube is stronger than a rod.

I have a 1.4m clear acrylic rod with 16mm diameter however it is too flexible for its intended purpose (imagine supporting the ends and hanging a weight from the center).

Is it possible to increase/maximise rigidity through either increasing the diameter (max 25mm) and/or making it hollow?

Length must remain constant, and lower weight is preferable but not hard requirement.

Comment: it's not the hole that makes it stronger ... it is the same quantity of material being made into a larger diameter rod (tube)

Comment: @jsotola yes, I get that.

Comment: How much force is it carrying and how much can ir bend. thisway somebody can estimate if its even remotely feasible. Also your supplier may not have all the possible combination of tubes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to increase/maximise rigidity through either increasing the diameter (max 25mm) and/or making it hollow?

Yes, up to the point where the walls collapse.  For a solid rod, stiffness will go up roughly as the radius raised to the fourth power -- but weight goes up as radius squared.

For constant-weight tube, stiffness will initially go up as radius to the fourth (when the hole is small), then settle out to going up as radius squared.  Keep it up, and because the wall thickness has to go down with increasing radius to keep the weight down, the thing will get fragile and just plain break (squeeze a soda can for an idea of why).

> I have ... acrylic ... too flexible.

Materials selection may be an issue.  Unless you must choose acrylic because of its looks or other non-strength physical properties, you may want to use something that's just plain stronger.  Assuming that glass is right out, you may want to investigate other plastics for this job (or ask if there's a glass that you could use -- I don't know if you could get tempered glass tubes in those dimensions).

Comment: Thankyou - these approximations are helpful. I'm using clear acrylic as it is used for a lighting effect by shining an led through the end (imagine a light saber). It needs to be impact resistant so glass is not an option. I'm now considering a (rigid) carbon fibre core inside clear acrylic tube with a thin reflective layer in-between. Hopefully I'll be able to get adequate light through a 3mm wall thickness with a ring of leds on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining diameter but making it hollow does not increase rigidity. It actually reduces rigidity a little but *greatly* increases the rigidity you get per weight.

Consequently, that means that if you maintain the same volume of material, you can make it hollow so that you can obtain a larger diameter for the same weight and that would increase the rigidity for the same weight. At that point you will be limited by how thin the walls can get before buckling.

Another approach is to fill the hollow with some material of lower density that has good compressive strength for it's density to help resist inward buckling (i.e. foam). This would allow you to get even enlarge your diameter even more while maintaining more or less the same weight with even thinner walls. But there is also outward buckling.